# Disable NFC tag so it does not trigger reader

Tags: nfc

Is there a way to disable (kill) the NFC tag so that it doesn't trigger the reader. Without physical intervention.

My goal here is for the smartphone not to get triggered by a disabled NFC tag. Usually even if the NFC tag is empty the average phone will still scan it and show it as an empty tag and I trying to avoid this read action by programming NFC tag in a certain way.

Comment: What are you talking about here? Could you please elaborate, this question is very unclear as it is. You should realize that not every MCU has the same way to accomplish this (unknown to me) task.

Comment: By "kill" I assume "permanently" is also implied?

Comment: I think you are asking if you can program an NFC tag to not transmit an empty tag back to the reader.  Is that correct?

Comment: @vir Yes, if it's not possible to reprogram it back to working NFC - then permanent will also do the job.

Comment: @PeterM  Yes, I'm trying to reprogram tag so it does not transit empty tag to smartphone. I don’t know how interaction is handled between phone and tag, but my understanding that unless the tag is damaged phone will still pick up the tag, thus transmitting something. May be there is a command that instructs the phone that this tag should not be read. Or it's possible to corrupt it.  It can be temporary, but if not possible - permanently disabling of tag will also work.